# Can you boot ASRock Fatal1ty X99M Killer/3.1 headless?

Tags: boot, motherboard, headless

I have two of these computers both with ASRock Fatal1ty X99M Killer/3.1 motherboards. As their gaming days are behind them, I want to use them in a headless fashion given the 12 core Xeon processors.

In order to reduce heat, I removed unneeded peripherals. until only the graphics card remained. When these were removed, one would boot headless into Windows 11 and find the network while the other would not boot.

So far, I have updated the BIOS, reviewed all BIOS settings regarding graphics and booting.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of internet sleuthing, I became convinced this was not possible, even though one of my identical motherboards would boot headless just fine. Finally discovered the answer.

If you disable the ACHP sleep state from the default "Auto" it boots fine into Windows and finds the network. For some reason my other motherboard had the default already changed from Auto to Disable.

Comment: Great self-solved answer!

Comment: I guess the next question is why would the ACHP sleep state affect the ability to boot with no network card installed?

Comment: @JohnRennie but there is a network card on the motherboard. So I suspect it has to do with WOL or something like.

Comment: Good stuff, but please check again: Is “ACHP sleep state” actually the thing you changed? Or is there a typo? Is this maybe supposed to be _AHCI_, _ACPI_ or something like that?